# What does the WS-I BP2012 assertion mean?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, ws-i

Can somebody explain what this actually means? An example would be really helpful.

> WS-I: (BP2012) A document-literal binding contains soapbind:body
>   elements that refer to message part elements that do not have the
>   element attribute.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This message is related to the [WS-I Basic Profile](http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-2.0-2010-11-09.html), which attempts to clarify the subset of WSDL and other specifications that are generally interoperable.

In this case, BP2012 is associated with the following:

> A document-literal binding in a DESCRIPTION MUST refer, in each of its
>   wsoap12:body element(s), only to wsdl:part element(s) that have been
>   defined using the element attribute.

You would typically see this if one of the messages used in your web service is defined in terms of a `type` instead of an `element`, for example:

```
<wsdl:message name="MyMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="MyPart" type="xsd:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

To fix this, you will need to change your message so that the `part` is defined in terms of an `element`, something like:

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
        <xsd:element name="MyElement" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>

<wsdl:message name="MyMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="MyPart" element="tns:MyElement" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.com/"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

Alternatively, you may want to switch your web service from using a `document/literal` binding to using an `rpc/literal` binding. With an `rpc/literal` binding, parts are defined in terms of a `type` instead of an `element`.